# Reading file until blank line

Tags: c++, file-io, operators

After reading [Jerry Coffin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179910/jerry-coffin)'s answer on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409446/reading-until-user-enters-blank-line/4409554#4409554) I copy-pasted his code into my editor, and after some minor edits it compiled and run like it should.

Here is the code after the changes:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <istream>
 #include <fstream>

class non_blank {
private:
 std::string data_;

 friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream &is, non_blank &n) {
  std::getline(is, n.data_);

  if (n.data_.length() == 0) {
   is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
  }
  return is;
 }

public:
 operator std::string() const {
  return data_;
 }
};


int main(int, char *[]) {

 non_blank line;
 std::ifstream ifs("teste.txt");

 while(ifs >> line) {
  //std::cout << line; <----- error
  std::string s = line;
  std::cout << s << std::endl;
 }

 return 0;
}
```

- I've got an error when trying to use a non_blank variable in a `std::cout <<...` expression. Shouldn't I be able to use a variable of the type non_blank anywhere I would use a std::string? Isn't it the purpose of the cast/conversion operator?? [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044690/operator-stdstring-const/3044700#3044700)
- Why can't I access the private variable `string::data_` directly in the definition of the `operator >>`?

Here is the error I got:

```
..\main.cpp: In function `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, non_blank&)':
..\main.cpp:21: error: invalid use of non-static data member `non_blank::data_'
..\main.cpp:26: error: from this location
```

Comment: I didn't understand anything in your question neither in the code (because I don't know c++ very well), but, based on the title (reading file until blank line) here's my idea: why don't read every character and compare it against the one before it? if they're both '\n' then you met a blank line.

Comment: The code is fully functional: reads a file, line by line, until it encounters a blank line. In order for it to compile I needed to make some small changes. That's why I've asked those questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn't I be able to use a variable
>   of the type non_blank anywhere I would
>   use a std::string? Isn't it the
>   porpuse of the cast operator?

Not quite.  If the compiler sees you doing something that it knows requires a std::string, it can call your conversion operator to get one.  But in the case of the ostream operator <<, it doesn't have a single specific function to call, but rather quite a lot of them, all different and none matching precisely the actual type you mean to print.  So it lists a whole bunch of candidates, none of which is a strong enough match.  You need to define an ostream operator << for your type in order to make it print as it should.

As for your operator >>, you should make it not be a member of your class.  Declare it as a friend within the class declaration if you must, but write the function itself outside.

Comment: Thank you. As for the operator>>, why should I define it outside of the class, is it some "code convention"? And finaly, is the reason why I can't access the class variables directly inside the definition of the operator the fact that the operator>> is not a member function?

Comment: It certainly is conventional to define the stream operators outside the class itself, because they are not member functions.  As for why you can't access the members, try moving the function outside first and then see if it works (making sure to keep the friend declaration inside the class, of course).